How to make angular esbuild ng serve watch for Typescript project references with es-build?
Is there a way to make ng serve watch for Typescript project references with es-build?
(Or any arbitrary folder outside of the project root, for my case, in the node_modules folder).
Notes :

In may 2023 the angular team committed this.

But it doesn't seems to work anymore with recent version 18.2.6, the source code has been modified.

I have also found this comment, that provides a workaround, but it forces me to re-define my project references twice (once in the "references" attribute and again in the "compilerOptions.paths" attribute, in my tsconfig.json) and it looks likes more like a hack than an official solution.

